# Given $0\leq s <t,$ why is $E[(W(t)-W(s))^2 |F(s)] = E[(W(t)-W(s))^2]?$

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales

Let $(W(t))_t$ be the Brownian motion.
When showing$W^2(t)-t$ is a martingale, it is quite common to do the following:

Given any $0\leq s<t$, since 
\begin{align*}
E[(W^2 (t)-t)│F(s) ] & = E[(W(t)-W(s))^2+2W(t)W(s)-W^2 (s)|F(s)]-t\\ 
& =E[(W(t)-W(s))^2 |F(s)]+2W(s)E[W(t))|F(s)]-E[W^2 (s))|F(s)]-t \\
& =E[(W(t)-W(s))^2 ]+ 2W^2 (s)-W^2 (s)-t \\
& =(t-s)+W^2 (s) \\
& =W^2 (s)-s.
\end{align*}

However, there is one part which puzzles me:

> Why is $E[(W(t)-W(s))^2 |F(s)] = E[(W(t)-W(s))^2]?$

I know that if $W(t)-W(s)$ is independent of $F(s)$ due to property of Brownian motion.  But why is its square $(W(t)-W(s))^2$ also independent of $F(s)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a random variable $Y$ is independent of  a sigma algebra $\mathcal G$ then $f(Y)$ is independent of $\mathcal G$ for any Borel measurable function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. Since $f(x)=x^{2}$ is continuous it is Borel measurable.

By definition $f(Y)$ is independent of $\mathcal G$ iff $P(f(Y)^{-1}(A) \cap B)=P(f(Y)^{-1}(A)) P(B)$ for all Borel sets $A$ and $B$. This is true because  $P(f(Y)^{-1}(A) \cap B)=P(Y^{-1}(f^{-1}A) \cap B)$ and $f^{-1}(A)$ is also a  Borel set.

Answer (score 1):

We can prove it using the following fact:

$E[B^2_t -B^2_s | \mathscr{F}_s] = E[(B_t -B_s)^2 | \mathscr{F}_s] \tag*{(*)}$

Proof of (*):
\begin{align*}
E[(B_t-B_s)^2|\mathscr{F}_s] &= E[B_t^2-2B_tB_s + B_s^2|\mathscr{F}_s] \\
 &= E[B_t^2|\mathscr{F}_s]-E[2B_tB_s|\mathscr{F}_s] + E[B_s^2|\mathscr{F}_s] \\
 &= E[B_t^2|\mathscr{F}_s]-2B_sE[B_t|\mathscr{F}_s] + B_s^2  \\
 &= E[B_t^2- B_s^2|\mathscr{F}_s].  
\end{align*}

Now we prove that $W_t^2-t$ is a martingale:
\begin{align*}
E[B^2_t -B^2_s | \mathscr{F}_s] &= E[(B_t -B_s)^2 | \mathscr{F}_s] \tag*{(*)} \\
 &= t-s.
\end{align*}
So
$E[B^2_t -t | \mathscr{F}_s]=B^2_s-s.$

Comment: So my attempt above is not correct? And how do you obtain second equality in the first line?

Comment: I edited it. It may be more clear now.

Comment: Independence stated by OP is very true and the proof is also quite trivial. Why do you it is not true?

Comment: @Idonknow The indepedence statement you made is true.

Comment: @KaboMurphy: You are right, the claim is correct. I didn't express myself correctly. The point I wanted to make is that you can't  just say that because $E[W_t-W_s|\mathscr{F}_s] =  E[W_t-W_s]$ then we have $E[(W_t-W_s)^2|\mathscr{F}_s] =  E[(W_t-W_s)^2].$ It requires a justification. The proof I wrote is quite standard. You only need the properties of the Brownian motion.